# Store a PDF file in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, pdf, blob

How would you store a PDF document in a field in MySQL?

Currently I have a list of customers and each customer has a certificate with information about their account that they can give to other companies to prove that they're our customer. Currently their certificate is exported as a PDF and e-mailed to someone here at work (the customer gets a physical copy as well), and that person's mailbox is filled with these e-mails. I'd much prefer to just have it in the customer's record - allowing it to be accessed via the customer's file in our in-house CRM.

I considered putting the PDFs in a folder and storing their location as a `varchar` in the customer's record, but if the PDFs get moved/deleted/etc. then we're up a creek.

My understanding is that a `BLOB` or `MEDIUMBLOB` is the type of field that I'd use to store it, but I'm a little ignorant in this regard. I'm not sure how to store something like that in the field (what C# datatype to give it), and then how to get it and open it via a PDF reader.

Comment: Why are the PDFs vulnerable to deletes/moves?

Comment: any luck? if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: @dcaunt: Reception has access to the shared folder that they are in on the server, and that can't be changed. Reception also has a knack for f'ing with things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put it in the database, but the `BLOB` datatype probably won't cut it. The `MEDIUMBLOB` is normally sufficient.

[MySQL Datatypes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html)

```
BLOB, TEXT                L + 2 bytes, where L < 216
MEDIUMBLOB, MEDIUMTEXT    L + 3 bytes, where L < 224
LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT        L + 4 bytes, where L < 232
```

I've used this several times with very good results. Be sure to save the filesize too, as it makes it easier to retrieve it. Not sure if it applies to C# as it does to PHP.

If using prepared statements with parameters the data will automatically be escaped AFAIK.

Also I can see no real reason as to why the database itself would get slow when storing this type of data in it. The main bottleneck will of course be the transfer of the data. Also MySQL is sometimes restrictive about the maximum length of queries and the responses in particular.

Once you have it running, it's pretty neat, especially when dealing with lots of small files. For a small number of large files, this approach does not make sense, better use some backup system to deal with moved/deleted files.

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing. It's been in production for a couple of months right now and it's working well. I DID have to up the packet size for mysql otherwise restores from dumps would crap out as soon as they hit that table. I didn't have to store the file length, I just dump the bytes to the windows temp folder using temp filename and open the file.

Comment: Yes, the filesize is for serving directly over HTTP, where i've had trouble getting the right size from the data in memory.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.phpriot.com/articles/images-in-mysql is a good tutorial with some background information, and an implementation of storing images in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think that going with links instead of actually inserting the file into the database is the best way to go. Doing that will make the database very slow, and will be more trouble than its worth.

I would upload the files to a designated folder like "certificates" and made the certificate names go with a client number so they are easy to find and edit, remove etc. I have seen people store images in databases but even that is advised against.

If the method you wish is definitely a must, check out this article:

http://www.wellho.net/mouth/1001_-pdf-files-upload-via-PHP-store-in-MySQL-retrieve.html

It explains how to store, and retrieve .pdf files in a mySQL Database.

Best of luck!

Comment: Unoptimised this is true, serving the PDFs from a database will generally be slower than just storing the path and serving from disk.

Comment: +1 It may be much easier to store it on the filesystem and store a ref to it in the db, but the data integrity is terrible and backups have a better chance of going wrong. : I looked at that article, and there's some good stuff in there. I just have to figure out how to get my ORM working the way I need it to as well.

Comment: I'd say its also dependant on infrastructure and implementation. Oh, and sometimes fastest isn't always the best.

Answer (score -2):

> I considered putting the PDFs in a
>   folder and storing their location as a
>   varchar in the customer's record, but
>   if the PDFs get moved/deleted/etc.
>   then we're up a creek.

That's the approach I would take.  Then using some logic perhaps some BPEL type stuff - detect if any of the files move/delete and fire off a trigger to your DB to properly update the location/remove the location