# Save pdf form in mysql

Tags: pdf, adobe

Is there a tool/software that I can use for clients to save their pdf form online. Example: I have e generic fill-able pdf form online, have them fill it out online and save it on the fly. Is there something like that out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but why save it in the database? You could probably save it on the filesystem as well?

-> [store a pdf in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983726/store-a-pdf-in-mysql)

Comment: I don't want to save the whole file, but the information in it. Like they could click on on "Save" and it will save the file on our server.